# Every power of adjacency matrix contains zeroes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to find connected graph $G = (V, E), |V| \geq 3$ such that every power of his adjacency matrix contains zeroes.

I know that that graph will be path and adjacency matrix for even and odd powers would look like this (lets say for $|V| = 3$):

$M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
  M*M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 2 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 1\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
  M*M*M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 2 & 0\\
   2 & 0 & 2\\
   0 & 2 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
  M*M*M*M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   2 & 0 & 2\\
   0 & 4 & 0\\
   2 & 0 & 2\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
etc...

Zeroes and other numbers are changing their position for even/odd powers of matrix.

I don't know how to prove that there always will be zero for path graph with $n$ vertices for any power of his adjacency matrix. Maybe use an induction(I am not sure how to proceed with induction though)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of Robert Israel's hint is that a bipartite graph has no cycle of odd length. So a walk follows a sequence of edges, where we can repeat vertices. Now suppose $G$ is bipartite and we can walk from $v_{i} \to v_{j}$, where $v_{i}, v_{j}$ are in the same partition. The proof is essentially by algorithm. We begin walking at $v_{i}$. We move along one of $v_{i}$'s edges to a vertex $v_{2}$ in the second partition. Then since $v_{2}$ isn't adjacent to any vertex in its partition, you go back to a vertex in the first partition. So following this algorithm, it must take an even number of steps to start and end in the same partition, and an odd number of steps to start and end in opposite partitions.

Now if there is a cycle of odd length, we can follow that cycle to get a $v_{i}, v_{j}$ walk of odd length. Because in a bipartite graph, there is no such cycle, we cannot construct a walk of odd length to two vertices in the same partition.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I am afraid that I still cannot see the proof that every power of adjacency matrix contains at least one zero. 
**EDIT**: Does a power of adjacency matrix shows how many times I walked through the graph?

Comment: The entries in $A^{n}$ count the number of $ij$ walks of length $n$.

Comment: And zero will be in every power of $A$ because as you said in your answer: "we cannot construct a walk of odd length to two vertices in the same partition." is it right?

Comment: Right. So because of this, there will be $0$ entries in even powers of $A$. Now what about odd powers? We can only go from one partition to the other, right?

Comment: I think I get it now. For every odd/even power I must go to the $v_i$ from $v_j$ hence there will not be zero for this walk in this power. But for the next power (which will be odd or even) there must be zero for the same walk because I am returning to $v_i$ using a different way?

Comment: If you can return to $v_{i}$ in $n$ steps, you can't return to it in $n+1$ steps because of the bipartite graph's property of having no cycles of odd length.

Comment: Aaah! Now I see it, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if the graph is bipartite (with parts $A$ and $B$), any walk  starting in part $A$ will be in part $B$ after an odd number of steps and in part $A$ after an even number of steps.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it right. If I create two parts (A and B) from path graph then this graph is not bipartite because I can find at least two vertices in each part which are connected. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In your example, states $1$ and $3$ form one part and state $2$ is the other.  There is no edge joining $1$ to $3$.